# Android in drag and drop , Drop is not working

Tags: android

Here i put my code, when i drop my view(ImageView)it's invisible please help me

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ImageView ivfirst;
    private android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ivfirst = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);

        ivfirst.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) v
                        .getTag());
                String[] mimeTypes = { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN };

                ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(),
                        mimeTypes, item);
                View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                        ivfirst);

                v.startDrag(dragData, myShadow, null, 0);
                return true;
            }
        });


          ivfirst.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
             @Override
             public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction())
                {
                   case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                   layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();

                   // Do nothing
                   break;

                   case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                   int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                   int y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                   break;

                   case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
                    x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                   y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                   layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
                   layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;
                   v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                   break;

                   case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
                   x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                   y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                   break;

                   case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :

                   // Do nothing
                   break;

                   case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                   // Do nothing
                   break;
                   default: break;
                }
                return true;
             }
          });
        ivfirst.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                            ivfirst);

                    ivfirst.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, ivfirst, 0);
                    ivfirst.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

when I run The program its working properly but drop is not work,
please suggestion me where i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is because you do nothing in `ACTION_DROP`.
[Explanation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/DragEvent.html) for `ACTION_DRAG_EXITED`:

> Action constant returned by getAction(): Signals that the user has moved the drag shadow outside the bounding box of the View.

You have defined no behaviour for the dragged `View`, when it is dropped.

Answer (score 0):

I studied the Android Launcher code to see how they did drag and drop. I really like their object model. What they did, and it might be good for you to consider, is move the responsibility for handling drag and drop out to the ViewGroup in which all the draggable views are inside of. Touch events get handled there rather than in your views.

Two of the key classes:

DragLayer – implements a custom ViewGroup, which coordinates movement of views on the screen. The Launcher DragLayer is a subclass of FrameLayout.

DragController – This object is the controller that does most of the work to support dragging and dropping.

The other thing they do is not move the actual view until you drop the object you are dragging. It does not look that way though because on the screen you see a bitmap constructed from the view moving as your finger (or pointer) moves.